# get partial sequence clojure from a longer sequence

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Given a sequence ("a","b","c","d","e"), what is the best way to get a subsequence of it, like ("c","d","e")?

I looked up subseq but it requires a test which in this case I want to be able to just supply the position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `drop` & `take`:

```
(def data  ["a","b","c","d","e"] )
(take 3 (drop 2 data))
```

If the data is a vector (square brackets, notice change above), you can use `subvec`:

```
(subvec data 2 5)
```

To ensure it is a vector, it is easy to use `vec`

```
(subvec (vec data) 2 5)

=> ["c" "d" "e"]
```

---

If you haven't seen them yet, you may want to checkout these resources:

- [Brave Clojure](https://www.braveclojure.com/)   (both website & book)
- [Living Clojure](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920034292.do)
- [Getting Clojure](https://pragprog.com/book/roclojure/getting-clojure)

And, of course, [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)